# How To Prevent the Same Event From Being Painted Multiple Times? Currently Resulting in Multiple Layers of the Same Event Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome extension when scrolling the page of certain sites renders the same element over and over again resulting in a loss in performance. The render happens the moment I stop scrolling. This results in multiples of the same layer pancaked one on top of the other. In the image below you can see 3 layers stacked on top of each other (see red arrow) and a fourth about to join them (see blue arrow).

Question. How do I stop the extra layers? Should only render one layer.

I tried adding a scroll event listener so when it stops scrolling it doesn't show the component (built in React), thinking that it would affect the new element being rendered. It unfortunately targeted the layer on top by removing it and the next layer at the bottom of the stack would propagate up resulting in a flickering effect.

This doesn't happen on every page when scrolling.

- Does **NOT** occur on stackoverflow.com.
- Does occur of developers.google.com like this [one](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count).

note...

- the black boxes was me removing any sensitive information.
- the screenshot was taken by looking at Layers within Chrome DevTools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After working with another engineer on this issue, it came to light that we had a background script that was using an event listener to check to see if the page load was completed before rending the content script. Some pages on scroll-end would fire multiple completed events causing my component to render over and over again. We fixed this by adding another qualifier to make sure once the page was initially completed, it wouldn't fire again no matter how many completed events the page was throwing afterwards.